# Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols: Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, ios-simulator

This error keeps popping up. I tried messing around with the podfile and Googling various things, but it didn't help. Please help. What's the problem?

```
`Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols:


Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15.`
```

I don't know why. I didn't have this problem when connecting to firebase before, but I don't know why this problem occurs. Please help.